# How to get and run an attribute of value "{{aaa}}/{{bbb}}" in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to define a custom directive with angular. It can calculate a path based on some custom attributes.

HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input ng-model="ratio" />
  <hr/>
  Image:
  <span retina-src="{{server}}/{{originWidth}}x{{originHeight}}{{uri}}" 
        origin-width="111" origin-height="222" />
</div>
```

Angularjs code:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).
controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
    function Ctrl($scope) {
        $scope.ratio = 1;
        $scope.server = "http://some.com";
        $scope.uri = "/main.jpg";
        $scope.name = "abc";
    }
]).
directive('retinaSrc', ['$compile',
    function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                originWidth: '@originWidth',
                originHeight: '@originHeight'
            },
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                var realPath = tAttrs.retinaSrc;
                return {
                    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                        scope.$parent.$watch("ratio", function(o, v) {
                          scope.originWidth = scope.originWidth * scope.ratio;
                          scope.originHeight = scope.originHeight * scope.ratio;

                            console.log("realPath: " + realPath);

                            // !!! there is something wrong here
                            var value = $compile(realPath)(scope);
                            console.log(value);

                            iElement.text(value);
                        });

                    }
                };


            }
        };
    }
]);
```

You can see I can the text of `retina-src` as:

```
{{server}}/{{originWidth}}x{{originHeight}}{{uri}}
```

But I don't know how to evaluate it. I tried `$compile` in my code, but it doesn't work, instead, it reports some errors:

```
Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/jqLite/nosel
    at Error (native)
```

I also tried `scope.$eval(realPath)`, but it will report some other errors.

---

A live demo: http://jsbin.com/mufokegayuqa/3/edit

Comment: Why don't you simply add `retinaSrc: '@'`in your scope? You would have the compiled expression value directly in the scope of the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the $interpolate service to replace curly expressions: i.e. {{originWidth}}.

Example:

```
var url = $interpolate(iAttrs.retinaSrc)(scope.$parent);
```

Note: scope.$parent is necessary because your directive has isolated scope. Remember to inject $interpolate service into your directive function.